# chosen() for dynamically content loaded with jquery load()

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-chosen

I have a page that loads several select boxes dynamically in jquery and I cannot make them work with chosen.

`$('.select').chosen({})`

I have to apply `chosen()` to every `select` within the page, but it only works with the content that is not dynamically loaded.

The page I'm loading has a div which id is #form, and it is inserted inside another dive within the body of the main page as follows:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.button', function(){   
        $('.container').load( 'https://url-to-my-page.html' '#form', function(){
             $('select').chosen({})
        });
    });
```

I have tried to call `$('select').chosen({})` inside the function that runs when the load is completed, but i got an error: *chosen is not a function* :-(

I have also tried to put that inside the #form, but `.load()` does not bring the script into the div. :-(

I have tried to load the whole `https://url-to-my-page.html`, and although that duplicates the `html` and `body` tags, is the only way it works, but I don't think is very clean.

Any other solutions I have seen on other posts don't work for me. Any ideas where to call chosen?

Comment: Just to clarify, what i have to load is a form with several select boxes, not just the options for those boxes

Comment: Dear @Surfget the code that you have provided has some minor errors. for example $('.container is not closed by a single quote `'`, same as the url and the `#form`.

Comment: for dynamic loaded content, i'd always try to bind event handlers, using event bubbling: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Hi Gijoe, thank you for pointing that out, that's not the reason for the code not working, it was just a typo when posting it here

Comment: thanks errand, let me try that

Comment: Don't think you can delegate to initialise the plugin. Are your chosen scripts included on the page that is running the load? (not in the page where the form is coming from)

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){   
        $('.container').load( 'https://url-to-my-page.html' '#form', function(){
        });
        $('select').chosen({});
    });` not sure if I understood, this gives me the same error, _chosen is not a function_

Comment: No the ones that load the plugin not initialise it - most likely in the form of `<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.js"></script>`  This needs to be on the page and before your load script is called

Comment: Hi Pete thanks for your answer, the `<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.js"></script>` is actually called in the head of the page where i'm loading the form.

Comment: So it's on the same page as the js in your question above and included before it?

Comment: I have tried to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.js"></script>` inside the #form, but `load()` is not bringing that into the page

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your full page source so we can see how it is set up

Comment: Ok, I have managed to make the jsfiddle load other select boxes, but as you can see, chosen is not working.  https://jsfiddle.net/dzyggftn/2117/

Comment: I was able to modify your fiddle to init the loaded form by using the same callback you have above... https://jsfiddle.net/kpy18nf3/